# How would this C# copy object routine translate to F#?

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I think this code I wrote to copy object property trees is pretty functional - does the F# version bring another level of succinctness?

```
public static class CopyUtility
{
    public static void Copy(object source, object target)
    {
        (
            from s in Properties(source)
            from t in Properties(target)
            where Matches(s, t)
            select Action(t, target, s.GetValue(source, null))
        )
        .ToList().ForEach(c => c());
    }

    static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> Properties(object source)
    {
        return source.GetType().GetProperties().AsEnumerable();
    }

    static bool Matches(PropertyInfo source, PropertyInfo target)
    {
        return source.Name == target.Name;
    }

    static Action Action(PropertyInfo source, object target, object value)
    {
        if (value.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System."))
            return () => source.SetValue(target, value, null);
        else
            return () => Copy(value, source.GetValue(target, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: what about properties of the properties? is this intended to be shallow copy?

Comment: it recurses in Action to make it deep unless i'm missing something which is possible - i tested properties with properties in a simple case though...

Comment: I'm probably the one who missed something, not you

Comment: I don't see why the action is deferred... (but only the immediate ones)

Comment: no good reason just experiementing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the C# copy function translated to F#:

```
module CopyUtility

let rec copy source target =
    let properties (x:obj) = x.GetType().GetProperties()
    query {
        for s in properties source do
        join t in properties target on (s.Name = t.Name)
        select s }
    |> Seq.iter (fun s ->
        let value = s.GetValue(source,null)
        if value.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System.") 
        then s.SetValue(target, value, null)            
        else copy value (s.GetValue(target,null))
    )
```

**Light syntax**

F# uses a light syntax where white space is significant, which reduces the number of lines taken by curly braces. I counted 28 lines in the C# code versus 13 in the F# code.

**Type inference**

The F# `copy` function requires only a single type annotation. Like C#, F# is a statically typed language, however F#'s [type inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233180.aspx) is not limited to [local variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383973.aspx).

**Nested functions**

F# supports [nested functions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Values_and_Functions#Nested_Functions) allowing the `properties` function to be defined within the body of the Copy function. This could be also be done with C# by defining a [lambda function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397687.aspx) of type `Func<object,IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>>` but it is considerably less succinct.

**Query syntax**

F# 3's [query expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh225374.aspx) provide a succinct syntax similar to LINQ in C#.

**Pipelining**

The F# [pipe forward operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229.aspx) (|>) enables function calls to be chained together as successive operations, often removing the need for temporary variable declarations.

Comment: Technically even the `: obj` annotation is not needed, as all objects support `GetType()`.

Comment: @AaronAnodide - Also, the C# version is looping through all the joined properties twice with `.ToList().ForEach` while the F# version is only looping once with `Seq.iter`.